# How does the "Taken Over" event card impact buildings and zombie movement?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

I played Last Night on Earth for the first time and I was playing the zombies.  I pulled the Take Over event card which states:

> Roll a Random Building and place a Taken Over marker on it.
>
> Place a Zombie from the Zombie Pool in each empty space of this
>   building.  No Hero may enter this building or Search here.  If the
>   building has already been Taken Over, Re-roll. Zombies placed here may
>   not move this turn.

I have a couple of questions:

- Does the building remain "Taken Over" even if all the zombies leave the building on subsequent moves?
- How does Zombie Hunger effect the event rule of "Zombies placed here may not move this turn"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The building remains taken over even if it has no zombies in it. The [Last Night On Earth wiki](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Card%3a%22My_God,_They%27ve_Taken_the...%22) covers the similar situation of drawing the *My God, They've Taken the...* card when all your zombies are already on the board:

> with ‘My God, They've Taken the...’ the building is always Taken Over even if no new Zombies are placed.

I think the zombies you place stay put for a turn even if there's a hero in an adjacent space, the Zombie Hunger effect doesn't override the no movement rule.