# What are the rules concerning Taken Over?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

When the player controlling zombies played the card, it said to fill the room with Zombies from the pool.
This reminded me of another card which said to move zombies from one part of the board to another if the pool was empty.

My question is, what happens when it says to "bring zombies from the pool," but there aren't enough to fill the room…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add as many as you can and don't taken them from else where.

This [BSE question here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11585/how-does-the-taken-over-event-card-impact-buildings-and-zombie-movement?rq=1) gives reference to the wiki.   Searching there will link you back to BGG [question here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/216527/my-god-theyve-taken-question), Where the publisher clarifies it with

> If all zombies are already on the board, then you don't place any new
> ones, but the building is still taken over.